# what the recommended control to implement table using winform?

Tags: winforms

Like to display the data to the table. What is the appropriate control in the winform to use?

Comment: We also have `DataGrid` control but `DataGridView` is appropriate and contains more features. I would recommend to have a look to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171628.aspx) for why it is preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)